# How to parse a JSON file in to an objects properties Angular 2

Tags: json, angular, parsing

I have seen a lot of answers on here, being able to parse a JSON object which is local to the component.
In my application I am accessing a big JSON file from a server/database. Therefore I have big JSON file which needs parsed in to my object different properties.

My object looks like this:

```
export class ICase {
id: number;
name: string;
description: string;
shareCaseXml?: string[];
fileType: string;
courtFolder?: string;
IPC?: number;
nicheID?: number;
date?: string;
suspects?: Array<ISuspect>
offences?: Array<IOffence>;
incidents?: Array<IIncident>;
policeOfficers?: Array<IPolice>;
involved?: Array<IInvolved>;
casedeit?: Array<ICasedeit>;
docEvidence?: Array<IDocEvidence>;
witness?: Array<IWitness>;
victims?: Array<IVictim>;
evidence?: Array<IEvidence>;
statements?: Array<IStatements>;
interview?: Array<IInterview>;
notebook?: Array<INotebook>;
complaint?: Array<IComplaint>;
}
```

I then have a method which uses a service to get the data from the database and assign it to the object "allCases". The problem I have is the JSON file looks a bit like this:

```
"templates": [
        {
            "name": "023-VMO-SubmitRemandFile-Case-013",
            "description": "1 suspect 2 offences, with bail",
            "shareCaseXml": "<nic:ShareCase xmlns:nic=\"http://psni.pnn.police.uk/si/nichedsm\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\r\n  <nic:Case AfterTimestamp=\"2015-02-04T14:44:00\">\r\n    <nic:ShareCaseReason>SubmitRemandFile</nic:ShareCaseReason>\r\n    <nic:InvolvedPersonsAndOrganisations>\r\n      <nic:InvolvedPersons>\r\n        <nic:InvolvedPerson Identifier=\"150000111000000000150343\" AfterTimestamp=\"2013-10-04T13:25:03.000\">\r\n
```

The "shareCaseXml" variable of the JSON object contains lots of variables I need to extract. My main concerns are 
-How do I access my components property to parse each variable of the big shareCaseXml variable
-Any of the examples I have seen already have their XML hard coded in to a local array, therefore I am unsure of how to access and then parse each individual bit.

All help would be appreciated! Many thanks!

Comment: Your backend should probably convert the shareCaseXml into JSON before serving it so that it can easily be consumed by your front-end Angular application. If that's not possible you're going to need to use a library like xml2json to convert it to JSON before using. You could build your own XML parser, but that's just going to be an unnecessary re-inventing of the wheel.

Comment: Yes that would make sense because at the moment I have a big string which I am unsure of how I am access!

Comment: Yup, my recommendation is to resolve the issue on the backend because it should return JSON or XML, but not a hybrid. This will become a nightmare in the long term if you're having to do special cases all over your Angular application to address XML potentially appearing in what is supposed to be JSON.